# Postgres Grouping of Like Results

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Our database is running on Postgres 9.3. We have a table called notifications.

Notifications contains `id, type, triggering id, source id`, and some other information.

What I am trying to do is select the notifications and then group them on their source ID.

So if I have the following:

```
id     type     source_id     triggering_id
1     comment     1234        4567
2     comment     1234        0123
3     comment     1234        5432
```

I would like to get the following back:

source_id, triggering_id(s)

I don't know if this is even possible. I'm pretty new to the DBA stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want a comma separated list of triggering_id's

```
select source_id, 
       string_agg(triggering_id::text,',') as id_list
from notifications
group by source_id;
```

Comment: Sorry I suck horribly at explaining this stuff. Basically I have the notifications table and I need to return groups of like notifications instead of looping through and returning them 1 by 1.

Comment: @AndrewGoldenberg If the query isn't returning what you want, you have to add the expected output based on your example data (edit your question)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name they may want just `order by source_id, ...`, without group by (i.e. *rows with same source_id "grouped" together*).

Comment: @ypercube: the part "I would like to get the following back: `source_id, triggering_id(s)`" lead me to assume Andrew wants a comma separated list.

Comment: I know, I assumed the same thing and was going to answer when I saw yours ;)